# Including static pages in the search index?

Tags: 7, search

I've got a page set up like this:

```
$items['mypage'] = array(
  'title' => 'My Page',
  'page callback' => 'mymodule_mypage',
  'access callback' => TRUE,
);
```

and then

```
function mymodule_mypage() {
    return 'This is a test! Also, pollywog.';
}
```

Now, if I go to /search/node/pollywog, I would like to see the above page as one of the search results. I currently don't, because I assume search just covers database content. Is there a way to make it also include specific pages? Something like the below would be amazing:

```
$items['mypage'] = array(
  'title' => 'My Page',
  'page callback' => 'mymodule_mypage',
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'includeInSearchIndex' => TRUE, // <<----- this!!
);
```

Would it be possible to build in something like "includeInSearchIndex" and then make that index the static page?

Answer (score 0):

Your module needs to implement [hook_search_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.api.php/function/hook_search_info/7.x), [hook_update_search](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.api.php/function/hook_update_index/7.x) and as part of that hook call [search_index](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.module/function/search_index/7.x) and then fully define how the content is indexed.

Out of interest why don't you just create static pages as regular nodes?

Comment: A lot of the pages are generated through custom functions. It's easier to write php that generates a list of products, than it is to add static text. I could probably use content types if I have to, but I really don't want to.